# How can I hide zeros in GridLookUpEdit?

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridlookupedit

I got form with GridLookUpEdit. `DisplayMember` type is DateTime. So I set GridLookUpEdit FormatType to DateTime and FormatString to `"d"`. But when I select row in GridLookUpEdit, selected value is displayed with zero-time, like `15.04.2014 0:00:00`. How can I avoid this thing?

Comment: The control is ReadOnly. And I select a row, not a cell, after that grid is closed, and zeros appear in editor.

Comment: It is the same issue. I think it is a matter of mask types. Try doing the same trick as the one in the answer for your GridLookUpEdit editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select a particular cell and if the cell is set to `Editable` then the cell's editor is shown. To use a particular cell editor, you have to add these lines of code :

```
// aDateColumn is the column you want to format
// Custom mask
RepositoryItemTextEdit columnEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
columnEdit.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.DateTime;
columnEdit.Mask.EditMask = "d";

aDateColumn.ColumnEdit = columnEdit;
```

More info [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1497).